# Window.beforeunload event is triggered in WebView in Android native app regardless of shouldOverrideUrlLoading return value

Tags: android, webview

In Android-WebView, I am trying to open the selected/touched link in external app by overriding shouldOverrideUrlLoading.

Window beforeunload event is triggered, regardless of return value of shouldOverrideUrlLoading.

My site according to current implementation is considering ("beforeunload event") as user navigating away from the page and marking the user as inactive, which is not correct.

Want to understand the behaviour of WebView, so that I can handle correctly.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) 
{
  if (request.getUrl().getHost().contains("mysite.com")) 
  {
     // same site load in WebView itself.
     return false;
  }

 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, request.getUrl());
 startActivity(intent);
 return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the method signature is should be next to override your desired action.

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
```

Other possible updates might be

1. to ensure you do NOT have multi window settings `mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);`
2. And sometimes you HAVE to set mixed content property `webView.getSetting().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);`.

Comment: This is not helping, it doesn't disable beforeunload event. When I use setSupportMultipleWindow(true), shoudOverrideUrlLoading is not at all invoked.. and the link does not open. With value, of false, link opens but beforeunload event is also triggered, like before.

Comment: @user1703205 Because this is how it works perfectly on my end. You are probably missing around things.